# What to use instead of the CDebuggerTab class?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am writing the CDT plug-in for the Eclipse IDE. Now I want to upgrade the version of supported eclipse from Mars to Neon and I have an issue related with the transition from CDT 8.8 to CDT 9.0. My plug-in has the class EmbeddedDebuggerTab which extends the org.eclipse.cdt.launch.ui.CDebuggerTab class but the latter was removed in CDT 9.0. I tried to find the way to fix this issue on the Internet but did not find anything. What can I do with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDebuggerTab is the debugger tab that was for configuring the CDI debugging. CDI debugger and all related classes were removed as part of [CDT 9.0](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn90#API_modifications).

If you are using a CDI debugger still, you hare going to have many more changes. However, if you were just using that class, but ignoring most of the implementation, you could extend the super-type org.eclipse.cdt.launch.ui.CLaunchConfigurationTab.

Comment: PS thanks for raising this issue, you helped me notice that we hadn't specifically pulled out the removal of CDebuggerTab and instead let that be caught in the general CDI cleanup category. I have updated the 9.0 N&N now.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I cannot just extend the super-type and I have difficulties with changing the old code.

Comment: @user2466068 You may have more luck on cdt-dev mailing list, I have helped others make the transition there

Comment: I have searched through this mailing list, this part https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg30671.html was helpful but it is still unclear what to do with the issue from the original post. I have such code https://gist.github.com/EvgeniyaKatunina/2c0401f441f1c6a8acdb8ad3fa3b0ac2 . Could you please advice me how can it be changed to match the new API?

Comment: (I meant post your question on cdt-dev. I am happy to help out extenders of CDT,  but SO isn't a good place for such conversations.) If you were reusing the tab for your own independent debugger (not CDI or DSF) then extract the relevant code from CDT's history and maintain it in your code base. Otherwise you will need to share more details.